# Win 10: Why the error popup "An invalid argument was encountered"?

Tags: windows-10, invalid-argument

While performing some actions in my application, I get this popup on Win 10 operating system (for example, when clicking on a button). Does anyone have any idea as to why such popup can show up on Win 10 OS? No sufficient information could be found online. The same application runs fine in different computer. Both the computers are Win 10 operating system.

Help in this will be highly appreciated. Thank you !!

Comment: Debug the program when the popup is visible and see why it's being disabled.

Comment: Don't have an option to debug as this is happening at beta site and not on developer's machine. So looking out for solution if anyone have solution to this popup.

Comment: The question provides no real details that would even make it possible to guess what went wrong. The string "An invalid argument was encountered" does exist in MFC, so maybe your app is written in MFC and it throw a CInvalidArgumentException? We don't have your app so we don't know how it could be doing that.

Comment: @RaymondChen Yes, the application is written in MFC.